# How to set new comment notifications alert for all pages in django?

Tags: python, django

Currently I'm trying to use signals to send notificaions if users get new comments. In website design, I set a `base.html` as the basic menubar loader. In the menubar there is a user avatar where I want to put numbers if users get new notifications. I tried to pass the notification numbers directly to the  `base.html` but it can be seen only in that page and disappeared in other pages. So does anyone know how to realize this function?

**Models.py**

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sender_userprofile", verbose_name="Sender")
    receivers = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="receivers_userprofile", verbose_name="Receiver")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField("Created Time", auto_now_add=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField('Is read', default=False)
    belong_cmt2mess = models.ForeignKey(CommentToMessage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="belong_and_mess",verbose_name="Comments belonged")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Notifications'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def mark_read(self):
        self.is_read = True
        self.save(update_fields=['is_read'])

@receiver(post_save, sender=CommentToMessage)
def create_msg_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    b_mess = instance.tar_mess
    sender = instance.com_nicknames
    receivers = instance.tar_mess.message_nicknames
    msg = Alert(sender=sender, belong_mess=b_mess, receivers=receivers, belong_cmt2mess=instance)
    msg.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make something available to every request you can write a context processor. These functions add to the context for every request so that you can access things everywhere.

These functions can be really simple, for example;

```py
def release_number(request):
    """
    Add the release number (version) to the context
    """
    return {
        'RELEASE_NUMBER': settings.RELEASE_NUMBER,
    }
```

They just need to return a dictionary similar to any usual context from a view. So you could have one of these to query your `Alert` model & get the notifications.

To add one of these, you add the dotted path to your function to the `TEMPLATES` setting options as below;

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': (
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ),
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Some related docs are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext